# Over-promiscuous bluetooth on Macbook Pro

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, bluetooth

So I have bluetooth stereo headphones ([Motorola s305](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BH3I9U)), that, now with iOS 4.1 and AVRCP, are a delight with my iPhone 3GS, at least, unless I happen to turn them on when my Macbook Pro is around.

Then the MBP thinks it's a pairing request and the headset's command is lost (worse: this happens while the MBP is sleeping, causing it to wake).  I think I once paired it with the MBP when I didn't have other headphones lying around, but I've tried to get the MBP to behave by

- Disabling "Discoverable"
- Unpairing, then removing the profile of the s305 on the MBP
- Telling my MBP to NOT allow BT devices to wake it up

Short of disabling bluetooth (would not be desireable - I like my Magic Mouse), what can I do to get my MBP to ignore the headset?

Comment: An interesting question… no idea yet. Will have to investigate this.

Answer (score 1):

I've had my Macbook Pro automatically connect to devices when they power up, but I've never seen a Bluetooth device automatically pair when it's not in the Bluetooth devices list.

I've never used Bluetooth headphones before, but it sounds like there's some sort of special case happening for audio devices, or at least this particular audio device. is "Prompt for all incoming audio requests" ticked in the Advanced options? It sounds like unticked would imply that audio devices would pair automatically.